How to convert CoreDispatcher to DispatcherQueue for AudioGraph event handler
Since CoreDispatcher has been deprecated in the WinUI 3 Windows App SDK and replaced with DispatcherQueue, how can the following code be converted to use DispatcherQueue properly?
fileInputNode.FileCompleted += FileInputNodeOnFileCompleted;

private async void FileInputNodeOnFileCompleted(AudioFileInputNode sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        sender.Stop();               
        sender.Reset();        
    });
}

Another reason to update the code to use DispatcherQueue is that when using CoreDispatcher in the code, the following error occurs:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

EDIT
Per YangXiaoPo-MSFT's request, here is a reproducible sample of the test app that contains the problem at hand.
The following is the XAML pertaining to it:
<Window
x:Class="Test_3_Take_2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test_3_Take_2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="recordStopButton" Content="Record"   Click="recordStopButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="playButton" Content="Play Recorded File" Margin="0,50,0,0" IsEnabled="False" Click="playButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>

And the following is the code behind:
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Media.Audio;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Media.Transcoding;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.Render;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;

namespace Test_3_Take_2
{


public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private AudioGraph graph, graph2;
    private AudioFileInputNode fileInputNode;
    private AudioFileOutputNode fileOutputNode;
    private AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutputNode, deviceOutputNode2;
    private AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode;
    private StorageFolder temporaryFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
    private StorageFile file;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = "Test 3 Take 2";

        var root = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
        if (root != null)
            root.Loaded += async (s, e) => await CreateAudioGraph();

        var root2 = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
        if (root2 != null)
            root2.Loaded += async (s, e) => await CreateAudioGraph2();
    }

    private void playButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (file != null)
        {
           
                TogglePlay();
            
        }

    }

    private async void TogglePlay()
    {
        //Toggle playback
        if (playButton.Content.Equals("Play Recorded File"))
        {
            if (fileInputNode != null) {

                fileInputNode.Dispose();

            }
            CreateAudioFileInputNodeResult fileInputResult = await graph2.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file);
            if (AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success != fileInputResult.Status)
            {
                // Cannot read input file
                return;
            }

            fileInputNode = fileInputResult.FileInputNode;

     fileInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode2);

                fileInputNode.StartTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

    graph2.Start();

    playButton.Content = "Stop Playing Recorded File";
          
      fileInputNode.FileCompleted += FileInputNodeOnFileCompleted;

    if (fileInputNode.Position == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
    {
        graph2.Stop();
        playButton.Content = "Play Recorded File";

    }
   


}
else
{
    graph2.Stop();
    playButton.Content = "Play Recorded File";

}
}


private async void FileInputNodeOnFileCompleted(AudioFileInputNode sender, object args) {
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        sender.Stop();               
        sender.Reset();        
    }); }

private async void recordStopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    await ToggleRecordStop();

} 

private async Task ToggleRecordStop()
{
    
             

    if (recordStopButton.Content.Equals("Record"))
    {

        playButton.Content = "Play Recorded File";
        playButton.IsEnabled = false;
        
        if (deviceInputNode != null)
        {

            deviceInputNode.Dispose();

            CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Other);
            if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                // Cannot create device input node
                return;
            }

            deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

        }
        
         file = await temporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("file1.mp3",
CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        // File can be null if cancel is hit in the file picker
        if (file == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        MediaEncodingProfile fileProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);

        // Operate node at the graph format, but save file at the specified format
        CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult fileOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(file, fileProfile);

        if (fileOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // FileOutputNode creation failed
            return;
        }

        fileOutputNode = fileOutputNodeResult.FileOutputNode;

        // Connect the input node to both output nodes
        deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(fileOutputNode);
        deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);
        graph.Start();
        recordStopButton.Content = "Stop";
        
    }
    else if (recordStopButton.Content.Equals("Stop"))
    {
        // Good idea to stop the graph to avoid data loss
        graph.Stop();
        

        TranscodeFailureReason finalizeResult = await fileOutputNode.FinalizeAsync();
        if (finalizeResult != TranscodeFailureReason.None)
        {
            // Finalization of file failed. Check result code to see why
            return;
        }

        recordStopButton.Content = "Record";
        playButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

private async Task CreateAudioGraph()
{
    AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
    settings.QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.LowestLatency;

    CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

    if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
    {
        // Cannot create graph
        return;
    }

    graph = result.Graph;

    // Create a device output node
    CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
    if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
    {
        // Cannot create device output node
       
        return;
    }

    deviceOutputNode = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;


    // Create a device input node using the default audio input device
    CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Other);
    if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
    {
        // Cannot create device input node
        return;
    }

    deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

    
}

private async Task CreateAudioGraph2()
{
    // Create an AudioGraph with default settings
    AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
    CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

    if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
    {
        // Cannot create graph
        return;
    }

    graph2 = result.Graph;

    // Create a device output node
    CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph2.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();

    if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
    {

        return;
    }

    deviceOutputNode2 = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;

}

}

}


Are you looking for DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue.tryenqueue

@SimonMourier If this is what will help achieve the end goal, how can it be implemented to make the code above work?

Did you see Change CoreDispatcher.RunAsync to DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT Yes, but how can that be adapted to this use case?

Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT A minimal, reproducible sample without private information has been added to the main post.

Not surprising. It works for me.

Update code:
bool isQueued = this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
{
    sender.Stop();
    sender.Reset();
});


Can you please share the code in the format that I shared code on the original post as well, along with the screenshot, for the benefit of everyone? Thanks.

@GiovanniBriones updated. It's almost the same as Change CoreDispatcher.RunAsync to DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue.

@YamgXiaoPo-MSFT Fantastic! This works! Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart! I really do appreciate it! Thanks again!
